# layout-land files does not works

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got the following problem. My program is a stopwatch. I have `res/layout/main.xml` and `res/layout-land/main.xml`
       But it works wrong. When I turn my phone, the program stops. I think it calls onCreate again. I added following line to the Manifest

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

but after this layout activity doesn't load.

I have tried next example, but it doesn't work

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
  switch (ot) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
     setContentView(R.layout.main_land);
     break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     break;
  }
 Toast.makeText(this, "Helloo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
  switch (ot) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
     setContentView(R.layout.main_land);
     break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     break;
  }
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include the following command in AndroidManifest.xml i.e., **android:configChanges="orientation"**, you're **manually disabling** the default layout-change behaviour, which is to re-start your activity in the new orientation.

The very useful thing to know is that you will need to manually change the layout used when you get **CONFIGURATION_LANDSCAPE/CONFIGURATION_PORTRAIT** in onConfigurationChanged.

Note that according to the documentation of the Activity from the Android Developers Website, onConfigurationChanged is a 'last resort' option - it's generally better to persist state and let the system re-launch your app.

The link for referring is as follows:-[Link for handling Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29).I hope this works for you.